# Why is bundler picking up the wrong ruby version?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, bundler

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2
$ ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
$ ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
$ which ruby
/home/sardsapp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby
```

I don't even know where to start with this. I even rebooted the machine, those commands are verbatim. I can't figure out what could possibly going wrong.

My Gemfile *does* specify 2.7.2, and that *is* my default version of ruby through rvm. I uninstalled all the other rvm versions of ruby. I don't have the ubuntu ruby package installed.

Comment: Post your Gemfile and the relevant section of your Gemfile.lock. You may also need to include your *PATH* and any non-secrets in your project's .envrc or similar.

Comment: A couple more things, on top of a Todd’s questions: What is your Bundler version? Are you setting the current Ruby version via a `.ruby-version` file in the project director?

Comment: `which bundler`? `gem env`?

Comment: Don't forget there's a system Ruby that can get in the way.

Comment: - I said in my post that my Gemfile specified 2.7.2.

Comment: I have a .ruby-version, it also says 2.7.2.

Comment: I don't have a system ruby installed.

Comment: I uninstalled the bundler gem and reinstalled, same problem.

Comment: ruby version in Gemfile.lock is also 2.7.2

Comment: The Ruby 2.7.0 isn't coming from nowhere, it must be on your system and it must be somewhere in your `PATH`. You need to track it down. Worst case: `find / -name ruby`.

Comment: Note: When I say `which` I mean the shell command that tells you which executable it will run. I know you specified the version, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: I grepped every file for 2.7.0 and didn't find anything, double-checked my $PATH and everything that effects environement (.bash*, .profile, /etc/*, .env, etc), uninstalled bundler and reinstalled, rebooted several times. Nothing.

In the end I removed rvm and went with the ubuntu package of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new gemset and switch the ruby version to 2.7.2